# Задания по javascript.Сделать атрибутом класса Country массив городов

Tags: javascript

Создать класс Country. У сущности Country должны быть атрибуты: имя, массив городов, которые входят к Стране. Создать методы добавление города к стране, удаления города за имям.

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, каким методом лучше удалять город из массива? Оставлять массив "дырявым"? Полностью перестраивать массив? Как бы вы это сделали, с помощью каких инструкций?

Comment: В задании не указано, да и основная проблема не в том, не могу понять как сделать атрибутом класса массив городов.

Comment: Атрибут, здесь - свойство. Изначальные свойства можно задавать при создании экземпляра класса, а значить передавать этот массив (или данные, которые будут преобразованы в массив) конструктору. Можно и прописать отдельный метод класса, который будет принимать массив городов уже после создания объекта.  Можно прописать метод `set` для задания свойства. Что предпочитаете?

Comment: С помощью конструктора, покажите пожалуйста пример кодом, если можете.

Answer (score 0):

```js
class Country
{
  constructor(name, citys)
  {
    this.name = name;
    this.citys = citys;
  }
  
  addCity(cityName)
  {
    // Реалезуйте сами
  }
  
  delCity(cityName)
  {
    // Реалезуйте сами
  }
}

const test = new Country('Германия', ['Ротенбург', 'Мюнхен']);
console.log('Массив городов:', test.citys);
```